# how to remove selected options in dropdown

Tags: reactjs

I want to remove the selected option and return the default value.What should I do? I got Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null on handleSelectChange function

```
<div className="pull-right" >
   <Select className="card-select" value={this.state.setting} 
                        options=
                            {this.state.deviceList.map((item) => (
                            { value: item.setting, label: item.setting }
                            ))}  
                    onChange={this.handleSelectChange.bind(this, "setting")}
                    />
                    </div>
```

handleSelectChange function

```
handleSelectChange(name, event) {
var nextState = {};
nextState[name] = event.value;
this.setState(nextState);}
```

Comment: which lib you are using for `Select Field`? check the doc about `onChange` method what it gets in arguments.

Answer (score 0):

From your onChange you are binding handleSelcetChange with this (refers to your handleSelectChange object) and "settings" (name parameter of your handleSelectCange), so you are passing the string "settings" as the name and you are not passing event.

Your argument for name is string "settings" and that of event is null. So event is null and hence the error.

Your onChange function should be as follows

```
onChange={this.handleSelectChange.bind(this, NAME_PARAMETER, EVENT_PARAMETER)}
```

Comment: bind only adds to arguments and not just passes those arguments, so without information of which library is used for Select its not possible to know whether event is defined or not

Comment: the 1st argument to bind function is always the object you want to reference, if you are binding the functions, the next arguments to the bind function will be the parameters you want to pass

Comment: In the question nothing has been passed for the event in handleSelectChange function so event is null and thus the error

Comment: onChange can actually pass the event to the function from within the Select component, so its not right to say that event is not passed

Comment: In this case i don't think so. No other events are triggered and onChange on Select component. Yes It is possible to bind it later. It is highly unlikely that someone will use onChange as props. But the error shows that none of that happened.

Comment: Select is not the HTML select as can be seem from the OP question, its a React component, could be a react-select or any other library and even it it was normal select, the event will be passed to the handleSelectChange function even without passing it with bind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172876/discussion-between-prajval-m-and-shubham-khatri).